# Text animation from left and right in continuous loop using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to animate text smoothly from left and right in continuous loop can anyone suggest me something here is the fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/yLNGn/3/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.kp').animate({
        left: '10px'
    }, 600);
    $('.kp').delay(600).animate({
        left: '-128px'
    }, 600);
    $('.rp').delay(2000).animate({
        left: '10px'
    }, 600);
    $('.rp').delay(600).animate({
        left: '-108px'
    }, 600);
    $('.kpp').delay(4000).animate({
        left: '10px'
    }, 600);
});
```

Comment: So you want to run the sequence you've posted above and then re-start that sequence so that it continues to run in perpetuity? Or is there another aspect to your question?

Answer (score 1):

See Here is the answer. I make it as the seperate function with fiddle see here.

```
function repeat() {
    $('.kp').animate({
    left: '10px'
}, 600);
$('.kp').delay(600).animate({
    left: '-128px'
}, 600);
$('.rp').delay(2000).animate({
    left: '10px'
}, 600);
$('.rp').delay(600).animate({
    left: '-108px'
}, 600);
$('.kpp').delay(4000).animate({
    left: '10px'
}, 600);
    $('.kpp').delay(600).animate({
        left:'-108px'
   },600 ,function() {
        repeat();
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vicky081/yLNGn/17/)

Hopefully it may helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use setInterval function, or if you make use of the complete callback of the jquery animate method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log('ready');

  var james = $('#bond');

  var right = function () {
    james.animate({left: '100px'}, 600, left);
  };

  var left = function () {
    james.animate({left: '0px'}, 600, right);
  };

  right();
});
```

this is the complete fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/yLNGn/32/

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [this jQuery plugin](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html)?